# App crashes with memory Pressure every time in IOS?

Tags: ios, crash, memory-pressure

I am generating image from view using following functions

```
-(void)preparePhotos 
{
    [assetGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
     {
         if(result == nil)
         {
             return;
         }

         NSMutableDictionary *workingDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
         UIImage *img = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[result defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage]] resizedImageToSize:CGSizeMake(600, 600)];
         [workingDictionary setObject:img forKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
         [appdelegate.arrImageData addObject:workingDictionary];
     }]; 
}
```

But as the number of times this function is called is get increased , app get crashed. How can I optimize this function or any alternative function to get image from device gallery which will not result into crash.function call like this.

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(preparePhotos) withObject:nil];
```

Comment: It seems you are storing all the images in arrImageData,is that so?

Comment: yes , i can store all images in arrImageData.

Comment: You are trying to create an array which will potentially hold **a lot** of images that's probably why you're running out of memory. If you explain what you're trying to achieve it might be easier to suggest alternatives.

Comment: hello @GadMarkovits , i want to get all images from device gallery and than display all those images in to a custom gallery in my app.

Comment: I see. Well, in order to be memory efficient you shouldn't hold all of the images in an array, you might just hold the asset url of the image and fetch the image as needed. Here's a [tutorial](http://brandontreb.com/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-an-image-gallery-like-over-part-1) of how to create a photo gallery.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch all the images from photo library than you should only store their Assets urls only not the images themselves. Lets say you are storing the Assets url in an array named `photoAssets` than you can call this method by passing just the index:

```
- (UIImage *)photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    ALAsset *photoAsset = self.photoAssets[index];

    ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = [photoAsset defaultRepresentation];

    UIImage *fullScreenImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[assetRepresentation fullScreenImage]
                                                   scale:[assetRepresentation scale]
                                             orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    return fullScreenImage;
}
```

and for more information or reference you should refer [PhotoScroller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/photoscroller/Introduction/Intro.html) and [MyImagePicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010135)